# Getting around Firefox not passing the file path

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I need a means of getting past Firefox's irritating refusal to pass the full path of a file selected using the input file element.  This issue has come up in multiple other forums and I haven't found any solutions that are helpful.

What I want is a means, via javascript, to open a file dialog (without using the silly "hidden file input element that you just call click on" method because that doesn't solve anything).  Then, when the user selects a file, I stow the full path in a regular text field.  The question: is that feasible at all?

If not, I don't suppose anyone knows of a handy place to find all the properties and relevant functions to call on a javascript file object.  For example

```
<input type="file" name="file_upload" onchange="alert(this.items.item(0).some_property)">
```

I found a handy list [here](http://www.ab-d.fr/date/2008-07-12/) but I'm keeping my fingers crossed that there's a property corresponding to a full file path (I know, wishfull thinking I'm sure).  Anyways, comments are greatly appreciated (unless you just tell me to stop whining about something Firefox has no intention of fixing).

Comment: Why are you trying to circumvent a security feature of the browser? This is NOT a <del>TUMOR</del> BUG.

Comment: The server should never require the full path to the client file. You're trying to do something that shouldn't be done, and there isn't any work around for it.

Comment: Stop whining about something Firefox has no intention of changing. ;-) But seriously, browser security features are annoying but important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would the server ever need to know the full path on the client?

Regardless of why, this is intentional behavior, as exposing this kind of information is a security risk.

It is highly unlikely to change, an any workarounds you may find may end up being shut down by browser writers as the security risks that they are.

Comment: I'm working with a legacy document upload system that takes the uploaded path and splits it into 3 tokens: the file name, file extension, and file path.  However, looking through the old code, I can't see anywhere in our system where the path is actually being used.  The entire purpose seems to be on the level of: "hey, remember that file you just uploaded?  No?  Well here's the path, do you remember now?"  Kind of useless so consider the question rescinded.  Thanks for all the replies though - except for Byron Whitlock...what a punk :)

Answer (score 4):

This is an intentional security feature and unlikely to go away.

Internet Explorer 8 does [the same thing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection) now:

> Additionally, the “Include local directory path when uploading files” URLAction has been set to "Disable" for the Internet Zone. This change prevents leakage of potentially sensitive local file-system information to the Internet. For instance, rather than submitting the full path C:\users\ericlaw\documents\secret\image.png, Internet Explorer 8 will now submit only the filename image.png.

Flash-based uploaders like [SWFUpload](https://web.archive.org/web/20140712223417/https://code.google.com/p/swfupload/) should be able to store the full path with some tweaking.