# Fetching file path from file upload control in mvc using jquery is not working in FIREFOX

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

[image]

I have an mvc textbox control and fileupload control as shown in the image. and here is the markup and js code and the action method....

```
<div>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="txtusername" /></div>
<div>
    <input type="file" id="fileupload" /></div>
<div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" id="btnsubmit" value="update/submit" onclick="fnupdatedetails(this)" /></div>
```

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateDetails(FormDetailsBE formDetailsBE)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public class FormDetailsBE
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string FileUpload { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the js code...for IE which is fetching the file path correctly
[image]

Here is the js code...  for firefox which is not fetching the file path

[image]

the same js code acting differently in diff browsers... some one please help. i'm stuck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying to upload file using ajax in mvc

Comment: i'm collecting all the info (textbox value, fileupath ) and constructing a JSON and posting it to controller's ActionMethod. Which is working fine in IE... even firefox post's the data but just the filename instead of filepath. Please let me know what is going wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3284066/55209

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not allowed for security reasons. The client side file path is never sent to the server. There was a bug in older versions of Internet Explorer where this path was sent but in new versions but this bug is fixed in the recent version. The server shouldn't need to know the file path on the client computer.

Comment: Thanks Darin Dimitrov, I was waiting for your inputs. I'm using IE 8... it is working fine locally... But in dev env this functionality is failing. not working in firefox locally also.  Please provide me an alternative solution. (Note: I need to pull the data using jquery and i need to post to controller)

Comment: An alternative solution is to add another text input field (not file) in which to ask the user enter the file path. As I already stated in my answer, for security reasons, FireFox doesn't send the path to the server and there's not much you could do about it.

Comment: Thanks Darin Dimitrov, You mean to say use a textbox and browse button instead of file type. That will solve my problem? This will work for all browsers? it will work even after deploying the code on some other location....?

Comment: No, I mean to have 2 textboxes: one file upload where the user will select the file and another simple textbox where he will manually enter the path to the file. If you use simple textboxes you won't be able to get the uploaded file on the server which is what I thought is your original goal. But the big question is: WHY DO YOU NEED THIS PATH ON THE SERVER?

Comment: oh... dimitrov... customer experience or UI experience would be bad right

Comment: Customer experience would be even worse if you were able to read your customer's file structure from your web server, right? You didn't answer my question which I will repeat: WHY DO YOU NEED THIS PATH ON THE SERVER AND WHAT DO YOU INTEND TO DO WITH IT?

Comment: dimitrov, i will not save the whole path on the DB. only the file name will be saved. But while uploading we need the path right... else we will get file not found exception

Comment: What are you talking about? The file path that you are seeing is located on the CLIENT COMPUTER. Not on the server. What you have to do on your server is take only the filename (which you obviously already know) and store it in some folder ON THE SERVER.